# how can i assign external images which loads in both runtime & design time with relative path to where the exe is built?

Tags: c#, external, picturebox, relative-path, windows-forms-designer

I want to create a guide application using C# which contains screen shots , texts and links to other pages.

I know that later on I have to update the guide application with its images.
The application including images is arround 2 MBs for each language. so I want to update it with the differences.

The solution i was thinking of is having a simple **exe** with **PNG** files next to it.
So I just need to include the exe and the only PNG files that have changed in my **update patch**.

The exe loads PNG files using `PictureBox.ImageLocation` attribute with **relative path  to where the exe is built**. it runs ok. everything is fine but in Visual Studio's Designer it fails to load the images. It shows a cross sign on the Picturebox. The ErrorImage. I want to keep it relative because I use several PCs or maybe a team for the future.

Here is a sample project: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o20xzc96cv422g9/WindowsFormsApplication3.rar

Runtime:

[image]

Designer:

[image]

Works ok at runtime, fails at designer.

how can i assign external images which loads in both runtime & design time with relative path to where the exe is built?

Is there a better way to create low size patches?

Comment: I must be missing something about the question, obvious answer would be to put the images on your computer relative to where you build the exe...

Comment: @PeterRitchie yes as i said, the exe runs alright. but the designer fails to load it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @AlexTerreaux It is a cross sign on the Picturebox. The ErrorImage.

Comment: @AlexTerreaux I added a sample project and pictures if you want to see yourself.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee if the file is in the right place, the designer should find it.

Comment: @PeterRitchie But it does not find it. I placed a link in my question to see it yourself. Where is the right place for designer?

Comment: It's important to remember that the "current directory" is the Debug (or Release) directory when being run from Visual Studio--which is different, obviously, than Visual Studio's current directory.  Visual Studio's current directory will be the directory used for relative paths in the designer.

Comment: Yes, that probably means one copy of the file for the designer and another being deployed for the app while it's running.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes, i understand. but it does not seem to be a good architecture when another person sees the project. :D He may laugh at me.

Comment: You should be able to create directory off the project's directory (where VS thinks is the "current" to it) that is the same relative to where the EXE is deployed. That's a matter of creating the right path in your solution and telling VS what files to deploy.  E.g. from the project directory is there is `images\` you can to tell VS to deploy that directory (and contents) where it deploys the EXE...

Comment: @PeterRitchie Um, Is there a better way to create low size patches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by putting the images inside the **resources** of many **Class Library Projects**. So the project can be divided to so many parts, each part has its own data that can be updated later with **lower sizes**.